# Unity UI Elements Move Animation Using iTween

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, itween

I was using iTween for giving animation to each main menu elements.
But animation not get played as per desire thinking, something different is running so I become confused about this for a solution.

I want to play game title, move animation from 1200 units to 0 unit using iTween move animation. But something like this, I was getting a result - it get stopped on -540 units:
[image]

This kind of code, I have written for UI Image move animation:

```
iTween.MoveTo (ballTitleObj, iTween.Hash ("x", 0f, "speed", 100f, "delay", 1f));
```

I know iTween work with Transform component and UI element with work RectTransform but what I require to do for a solution?

Comment: Where are you calling `iTween.MoveTo`? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52873463/edit) your question to include the code that calls `iTween.MoveTo`.

Comment: Above code definitely get executing because, from units 1200, my title get moving animation to -540 units

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, get the `RectTransform` of the title:

```cs
this.titleRectTransform = ballTitleObj.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
```

Then, call `iTween.ValueTo`, because you don't want to change the transform, you need to change the `RectTransform`.

```cs
iTween.ValueTo(ballTitleObj, iTween.Hash(
    "from", this.titleRectTransform.anchoredPosition,
    "to", new Vector2(0, this.titleRectTransform.anchoredPosition.y),
    "speed", 100f,
    "delay", 1f,
    "onupdatetarget", this.gameObject, 
    "onupdate", "MoveBallTitle"));
}
```

And in the same class that you are calling `iTween.ValueTo` in, you need to define a `MoveBallTitle` method that updates the anchoredPosition:

```cs
public void MoveBallTitle(Vector2 position){
    this.titleRectTransform.anchoredPosition = position;
}
```

This answer is based off [this answer](http://answers.unity.com/answers/1016004/view.html) on the Unity Q&A site

Comment: okay let me check within actual project because this is perfect answer for my question so I don't require to switch from iTween to other

Comment: Awesome thanks for this answers - worked perfectly for me...:)

Answer (score 0):

Okay now spending enough time for this problem, I find at least one solution for this.

I started using DOTween rather than iTween:
[DOTween - Documentation](http://dotween.demigiant.com/documentation.php)

Its in-built contains support for Unity UI animations and I can able to get implemented easily within the project. Here is the code line that worked for me:

```
ballTitle.DOAnchorPosX (0f, 1f, false).SetDelay (0.5f).SetEase(Ease.OutBack);
```